# How to add text next to existing Text in a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, function

[![i want to click On Male And it Reflects next to Gender : Male  in the Text Area
]

I got this Script for example and I want the option when I click On the button Male it shows next to Gender: inside the `textbox`, if I click on Female it goes right next to male like this male,female ?

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
      <head>
        <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', start, false);
            function start(){
                document.getElementById("button0").addEventListener("click", function(){insertText(this);} );
                document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){addText(this);} );
                document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){addText(this);} );
                document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function(){addText(this);} );
    document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click", function(){addText(this);} );

                function addText(elem) {

                    document.getElementById("ta1").innerHTML += elem.value;

                }
            };


    </script>
 </head>
 <body>


Gender

        <br>
        <input class="button" type="button" id="button0" value="Male"/>
        <input class="button" type="button" id="button1" value="Female" />
        <input class="button" type="button" id="button2" value="Not Required"/>
<br>

etc
<br/>
        <input class="button" type="button" id="button3" value=" 1 "/>

  <input class="button" type="button" id="button4" value="2"/>


<textarea id = "ta1" disabled rows="20" cols="80">
Gender: 
Etc:

 </textarea>

</body>
</html><html>
```

Image of the textbox:

[image]

Comment: Please post an image of the text box, because it's unclear what you want to do.

Comment: okai ill add a picture right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit** Code i've test :

```
<script>
function btnGenderClick(type,value)
{
    document.getElementById("test").value+= type+" : "+value+'\r';
}
</script>
<input type="button" value="Male" onClick="btnGenderClick('Gender','Male')" name="Male">
<input type="button" value="Female" onClick="btnGenderClick('Gender','Female')" name="Female">
<input type="button" value="Not required" onClick="btnGenderClick('Gender','Not required')" name="NotRequired">
<textarea id="test"></textarea>
```

Comment: tried it , Showed me empty buttons can you add it to mines and send it , i might've done something wrong

Comment: i've forget the value on the button but it work for me

Comment: can you show me the complete code you used ? please ?

Comment: it works , but how can i add the other Thing in the New Line ,, for example 
Gender : Male
ETC : 1 Or 2 Or 3
popcorn : 1 or 2 or 3 ?
without replacing , for example When Click on male it becomes Gender : male 
when pressing on female it goes
Gender : Male , Female

Comment: In the other function use += "document.getElementById("test").value += 'Code here'"

Comment: because it just Replaces Gender : it doesn't Go in a new Line under it

Comment: Thank You sooo much Alexis , Another Thing , is there a way To make Multiple Genders in the same Line , because i i want to do it like
Gender : Male
type : Brown eyes , Tall , etc 
?

Comment: You can use more generic function with two parameter type and value and use the same function for each type of button

Comment: Edited, you can use other button with the same function and change the parameter example : onclick="btnGenderClick('animal','cat')"

Comment: Instead of `.value` shouldn't it be `.innerHTML`? As you are changing the inner HTML of the element and not its `value` attribute?

Comment: It's like an input for me it's better value but what's really better ? I don't know

Answer (score 0):

What you will want to do is store the text in a variable and append to it, changing the content of the text area each time one of the button is clicked. You will also have to make sure that if they go back to a button that was clicked that you don't append, but instead that you update what was previously submitted.

**EDIT**

Based on the example function that was shared by @Alexis, I wrote this working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
    <script>
    var genders = [];

    function btnGenderClick(value)
    {
        var options = ['Male','Female','Not Required'];
        genders.push(options[value]);
        document.getElementById("ta1").value= "Gender: " + genders.join() + "\nEtc:";
    }
    </script>
 </head>
 <body>


Gender

    <br>
    <button type="button" onClick="btnGenderClick(0)" name="Male">Male</button>
    <button type="button" onClick="btnGenderClick(1)" name="Female">Female</button>
    <button type="button" onClick="btnGenderClick(2)" name="NotRequired">Not Required</button>
<br>

etc
<br/>
    <input class="button" type="button" id="button3" value=" 1 "/>

  <input class="button" type="button" id="button4" value="2"/>


<textarea id = "ta1" disabled rows="20" cols="80">
Gender: 
Etc:

 </textarea>

</body>
</html><html>
```

The only thing that I don't understand is what Etc: is and what you want to put there.

Comment: yes but how to do that ? i'm not quite sure how it works inside the textbox

Comment: To change the value of the textbox you would do this: document.getElementsById("ta1").value = myValue;  you're using innerHtml which is not what you want to use for this.

Comment: what do you suggest using ? i'm really out of ideas  if you have any way i can do it , Can you show me An example script that works ? i'll build on it what i want to do

Comment: thats good , thank you too man , You And alexis solved this for me THANKSS :)